# How to find unique values of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a problem finding unique values of a matrix. 
This is my database:

```
structure(list(date = structure(c(1043971200, 1046390400, 1049068800, 
1051660800, 1054339200, 1056931200, 1059609600, 1062288000, 1064880000, 
1067558400, 1070150400, 1072828800, 1075507200, 1078012800, 1080691200, 
1083283200, 1085961600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    M1 = c("AMZN PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "ALICORI1 PE Equity", "ALICORI1 PE Equity", "ALICORI1 PE Equity", 
    "ALICORI1 PE Equity", "ALICORI1 PE Equity", "ALICORI1 PE Equity", 
    "ALICORC1 PE Equity", "ALICORC1 PE Equity", "ALICORC1 PE Equity", 
    "ALICORC1 PE Equity", "ALICORC1 PE Equity"), M2 = c("ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "BACKUAC1 PE Equity", "BACKUAC1 PE Equity", "BACKUAC1 PE Equity", 
    "BACKUAC1 PE Equity", "BACKUAC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity", 
    "ANDAHUC1 PE Equity"), M3 = c("AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "BACKUBC1 PE Equity", 
    "BACKUBC1 PE Equity", "BACKUBC1 PE Equity", "BACKUBC1 PE Equity", 
    "BACKUBC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", 
    "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", 
    "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", 
    "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity", "AUSTRAC1 PE Equity"
    ), M4 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", 
    "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", 
    "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", 
    NA, "BACKUSI1 PE Equity", "BACKUSI1 PE Equity")), row.names = c(NA, 
17L), class = "data.frame")
```

So I want to find the unique values for the matrix ( No matter the date or if it is M1 , M2 ,etc)

This is my code for unique values but for independent columns.

```
 final <-  testrepstack %>% summarise_all(list(~ list(unique(.)))) %>%  
                              unnest(everything())
```

But i want unique values for all the matrix. In mi excel sheet: from B2:E18 (just the cells with the characters I want to find unique values)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, it's currently stored as a data frame, not a matrix.

Try this:

```
unique(as.vector(as.matrix(testrepstack[-1])))
```